# How to debug OpenCV program without Nvidia DLLs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, nvidia, pdb-files

Visual Studio Community 2013
Windows 8.1 64bit
OpenCV 3.0 beta
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M
and a Intel core graphics.

When I want to debug a OpenCV program, all symbol files (.pdb) loaded succeed except nvinit.dll, detoured.dll, Nvd3d9wrap.dll, nvdxgiwrap.dll.

VS told me this:

'ImageWatchT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'ImageWatchT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'ImageWatchT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'ImageWatchT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.

Those four DLLs belong to Nvidia apparently.
So, how to debug without those four Nvidia DLLs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable symbol loading for a module thus:
(From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx)

> To change symbol load behavior for a specific module
>   In the Modules window, right-click the module.
>   Point to Automatic Symbol Load Settings and then click Always Load Manually or Default. Changes do not take effect until you restart the debugging session.

Comment: Thanks! And can I load my own PDBs only?

Answer (score 0):

To expand the other answer, in **Visual Studio 2010**, you do the following:

- Switch onto the "Modules" tab at the bottom
   [image: image description]
- Select any modules you want to skip
- In the context menu, select *Automatic load settings - Always load manually*

[image: image description]

You also can go into detailed settings via *Symbol settings...* in the same context menu. There, you can use whitelist of modules instead of blacklist, that is, you can only opt to load modules you want:

[image: image description]